# Is a cartesian product a group?

Tags: group-theory

Let $J= N \times R$ with operation $(a,x)*(b,y) = (a+b, (ax+by)/a+b)$. Is $(J,*)$ a group?

It is a cartesian product between natural numbers and real numbers. I am not sure how to prove whether it is associative.

Comment: Compute $((a, x)*(b, y))*(c, z)$ and $(a, x)*((b, y)*(c, z))$ and see whether they're equal.

Comment: thanks - I got (a+b+c, ax+by+cz/a+b+c) which is not equal to

Comment: (a+b+c, ax+b+c(by+cz)/a+b+c) so not associative

Answer (score 3):

$J$ has no identity element, since $(a,x) *(b,y)=(a,x)$, implies $(a+b,ax+by/(a+b))  = (a,x)$ and $a=a+b$, which show that $b=0$. Thus it is not a group.

Answer (score 2):

$*$ isn't even well-defined, so $(J, *)$ can't be a group. $(0, 0)*(0, 0)$ involves division by zero.

Comment: The first co-ordinate can not be zero, since it is a natural number.

Comment: @D.N.: Oh, you're assuming 0 isn't a natural. Your answer makes a lot more sense now. I'm working with a definition of N starting at 0.